# Type III von Neumann Algebras and Quantum Field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-gravity

In https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04993 , https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.12828, it is written that local algebras in quantum field theory are of Type III and these do not admit pure states, density matrices and von Neumann entropies. So what is the entanglement entropy that we usually define in CFTs like in the paper of Cardy and Calabrese https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4013. Maybe I am confusing something obvious.

Comment: I had a similar confusion, and haven't reached a complete understanding of the whole thing. But, despite the local algebras being type III_1 we are still able to calculate entanglement entropy in CFTs using the Cardy-Calabrese formalism because we assume a lattice regularization in the theory as a result the nature of algebra changes to type I and we can talk about Hilbert space factorization in terms of degrees of freedom in a given region and its complement region. Then we partial trace over the complement region in the path integral. The cost we pay is that the entropy is UV divergent.